# Registry entry for different SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, version, registry

Which are the reliable registry entries to see install versions of SQL Server? Like if I have 2005 and 2008 both installed on my machine, how can I check this in registry? Also how to check which is the default one?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

- [SQL Server Registry Hacks Top 10](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/1477361/SQL-Server-Registry-Hacks-Top-10.htm)
- [how to find the edition of SQL
  Server 2000/2005 through
  registry?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldocumentation/thread/8d6b5603-e030-4c6d-9872-afe4741a7d16)